# htaccess: how to redirect to a default page?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect the user using htaccess to www.xyz.com/some_folder_name/**custom_page.php** if the user enters `www.xyz.com/some_folder_name/` , in the browser, that is, in the situation, when no specific php page has not been specified.

Any suggetions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following configuration:

```
RewriteRule ^some_folder_name/?$ /some_folder_name/custom_page.php [L,R=302]
```

If you want the redirection to be a permanent one, change 302 into 301.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add your custom_page.php as default index page

DirectoryIndex custom_page.php ...